# Cleaning a data frame inputed with fileInput and plotting it - R Shiny

Tags: r, reactive-programming, shiny, shinydashboard

**Goal**: Create a shiny app that can take in data from the user using the fileInput() function and then clean the data that is being brought in with the help of dplyr and a lot of other data manipulation techniques and then plot this data and display a table of the cleaned data and also have a download button to download the cleansed data.

**What I have done**: I have successfully created the app without the fileInput. I simply cleansed the data using a R script and then added the script before the user interface portion of the app and ran the app and it worked fine. However, this did not have user input capability.

The code below is a simplified version of my ui and server side of the app that attempts to add user input functionality.

```
Dept <- c(1,2,3)
DepartmentName <-c("abc","def","ghi")
Dept_Names <- cbind.data.frame(Dept,DepartmentName)

ui <- dashboardPage(   
  dashboardHeader(title="ABC"),
  dashboardSidebar(width = 150,
                   sidebarMenu(  
          menuItem("DataInput",tabName = "DataInput"),      
          menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "Dashboard")
                   )),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "DataInput", 
              box(fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File',
                            accept=c('.csv')),
                  tags$hr(),
                  checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
                  radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
                               c(Comma=',',
                                 Semicolon=';',
                                 Tab='\t'),
                               ','),
                  actionButton("Load", "Load the File"))
      ),
      tabItem( tabName = "Dashboard",
               fluidRow(column(9,box(status = "primary",plotOutput("plot1"))
               ),
               column(3,
                      box(title="Controls",
                          selectInput(inputId = "Dept", 
                                      label = "Select", 
                                      choices = C(1,2,3)), 
                          numericInput(inputId = "ClassNum", 
                                       label = "Enter the Class Number", value = 1, min=0, max=100000),
                          status = "warning", solidHeader = TRUE, width="100%"),

                      downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download')

                )
              ), 
               box(DT::dataTableOutput("table"), width = "100%,",status = "primary")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input,output) { 

  data <- reactive({
    if(input$Load == 0){return()}
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile)){return(NULL)}

    isolate({ 
      input$Load
      a <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header,sep = input$sep,stringsAsFactors =FALSE)

      options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 
      a <- a[,1:5] 
      names(a) <- c("Dept","Description","Price","ClassNum","Quantity") 

      a <- a %>%
        filter(Quantity > 0) %>%
        filter(!(Price==""))  

      for (i in 1:length(a)) {  
        for (j in 1:nrow(a)) {
          if (i==2) {next}
          a[j,i] <- gsub(",", "", a[j,i])
        }  
      }  
      rm(i,j)  

      a <- merge(a,Dept_Names, by="Dept")

      for (j in 1:nrow(a)) { 
        if (a$ClassNum[j]=="") {a[j,4] <-0} else {a[j,4] <- a$ClassNum[j]}
      } 
      rm(j)

      a$Dept <- as.numeric(as.character(a$Dept))
      a$ClassNum <- as.numeric(as.character(a$ClassNum))
      a$Price <- as.numeric(as.character(a$Price))
      a$Quantity <- as.numeric(as.character(a$Quantity))

      a <- a %>%
        mutate(Revenue=Price*Quantity,Key1=paste(Dept, "_", ClassNum, sep="")) 

      total_complete <- a %>%
        group_by(Dept, ClassNum) %>%
        summarise(Revenue=sum(Revenue)) %>%
        arrange(Dept, desc(Revenue)) %>%
        mutate(Key1=paste(Dept, "_", ClassNum, sep="")) 

      ofn <- paste0("ABC",Sys.time(),".csv")
      ofn <- gsub(":","_",ofn)

    })

  })


  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = data()$ofn,
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(data()$total_complete, file, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )


  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable({data1 <- data()$total_complete[data()$total_complete[,1]==input$Dept ,]
  }))

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({

    ggplot(total_complete[total_complete$Department==input$Dept,], 
           aes(reorder(x=Key1,desc(Revenue)), y=Revenue, fill=Key1)) +
      geom_bar(stat="identity") +
      theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1,vjust=0.5)) 
  })



} 



shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The input data looks like this

```
Dept #  Description Retail  Class # Q
10  MOP 11.99   100 1
10  Broom   7.99    101 2
10  soap    5.99    102 3
10  key 7.99    103 4
10  salmon  34.99   104 5
10  steak   11.99   105 5
10  wine    9.99    106 7
```

Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used the data that you had provided above and I managed to debug your code.

- First of all I changed the last value of the variable `dept` to 10 and similarly the choices in `selectInput` because the merging of `a` and `Dept_Names` had resulted in an empty data frame and the app had crashed. To prevent crashing I added a function `validate` that requires that the data set `a` after merging is non empty.
- I changed `C` to `c` within `selectInput`
- `data` had no return value and I set it to the list where `total_complete` is a cleaned data frame and `ofn` is the name of the downloaded data frame:

  ```
  return(list(total_complete = total_complete, ofn = ofn))
  ```
- within two `render*` functions I added `req(data())` which prevents errors if the `data()` is not available (when it is `NULL`)
- added `data()$` within `render*` functions to `total_complete` and changed `Departments` to `Dept`

To get nonempty plot and a nonempty table, after uploading the data which you included in your question, set the value of the `selectInput` to `10`

I've made comments in the code to indicate all above changes.

**Full code:**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

rm(ui)
rm(server)

Dept <- c(1,2,10) # changed 3 to 10 to avoid an empty data set a after merging.
DepartmentName <-c("abc","def","ghi")
Dept_Names <- cbind.data.frame(Dept,DepartmentName)

ui <- dashboardPage(   
  dashboardHeader(title="ABC"),
  dashboardSidebar(width = 150,
                   sidebarMenu(  
                     menuItem("DataInput",tabName = "DataInput"),      
                     menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "Dashboard")
                   )),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "DataInput", 
              box(fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File',
                            accept=c('.csv')),
                  tags$hr(),
                  checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
                  radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
                               c(Comma=',',
                                 Semicolon=';',
                                 Tab='\t',
                                 Whitespace = " "),
                               ','),
                  actionButton("Load", "Load the File"))
      ),
      tabItem( tabName = "Dashboard",
               fluidRow(column(9,box(status = "primary", plotOutput("plot1"))
               ),
               column(3,
                      box(title="Controls",
                          selectInput(inputId = "Dept", 
                                      label = "Select", 
                                      choices = c(1,2,10)), # changed C to c and 3 to 10 
                          numericInput(inputId = "ClassNum", 
                                       label = "Enter the Class Number", value = 1, min=0, max=100000),
                          status = "warning", solidHeader = TRUE, width="100%"),

                      downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download')

               )
               ), 
               box(DT::dataTableOutput("table"), width = "100%,",status = "primary")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input,output) { 

  data <- reactive({
    if(input$Load == 0) {
      return(NULL)
    }
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile)) {
      return(NULL)
    }
      a <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header,sep = input$sep,stringsAsFactors =FALSE)

      options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 
      a <- a[,1:5] 
      names(a) <- c("Dept","Description","Price","ClassNum","Quantity") 

      a <- a %>%
        filter(Quantity > 0) %>%
        filter(!(Price==""))  

      for (i in 1:length(a)) {  
        for (j in 1:nrow(a)) {
          if (i==2) {next}
          a[j,i] <- gsub(",", "", a[j,i])
        }  
      }  
      rm(i,j)  

      # You have to be careful here because it can be an empty data frame!
      a <- merge(a, Dept_Names, by="Dept")

      validate(
        need(nrow(a) != 0, 'Merge was not successful')
      )


      for (j in 1:nrow(a)) { 
        if (a$ClassNum[j]=="") {
          a[j,4] <-0
        } else {
          a[j,4] <- a$ClassNum[j]
        }
      } 
      rm(j)

      a$Dept <- as.numeric(as.character(a$Dept))
      a$ClassNum <- as.numeric(as.character(a$ClassNum))
      a$Price <- as.numeric(as.character(a$Price))
      a$Quantity <- as.numeric(as.character(a$Quantity))

      a <- a %>%
        mutate(Revenue=Price*Quantity,Key1=paste(Dept, "_", ClassNum, sep="")) 

      total_complete <- a %>%
        group_by(Dept, ClassNum) %>%
        summarise(Revenue=sum(Revenue)) %>%
        arrange(Dept, desc(Revenue)) %>%
        mutate(Key1=paste(Dept, "_", ClassNum, sep="")) 

      ofn <- paste0("ABC",Sys.time(),".csv")
      ofn <- gsub(":","_",ofn)


      # It looks like that you want to return a list
      # total_complete is a processed data frame and ofn is a name of the file
      # that is going to be downloaded
      return(list(total_complete = total_complete, ofn = ofn))

    })


  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler( 
    filename = function() { # added a function as in an example from ?downloadHandler
      data()$ofn
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(data()$total_complete, file, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )


  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({ 
    req(data()) # require that data() is available
    DT::datatable(data()$total_complete[data()$total_complete[,1]==input$Dept ,])
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    req(data()) # require that data() is available

    # there is no such variable as "Department" hence changed to $Dept
    # added data()$
    ggplot(data()$total_complete[data()$total_complete$Dept==input$Dept,], 
           aes(reorder(x=Key1,desc(Revenue)), y=Revenue, fill=Key1)) +
      geom_bar(stat="identity") +
      theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1,vjust=0.5)) 
  })
} 

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear and concise answer and for fixing the issues I had. I was able to use your solution and more importantly understand it. Well written and conveyed.